# Constant Uninitialized in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I created a constant that includes my API key for an app I'm working on. It's working in the rails console, but I'm having a hard time getting this to work in my tests. I have to use Bing so I added the API like so:

```
# config/bing.yml
development:
  secret: 1234

test:
  secret: 5678

production:
  secret: abcd

# config/initializers/bing.rb
BING_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/bing.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

How would I ensure that `BING_CONFIG` loads into rspec? Currently, it's working and loading fine in the my rails console, but when I run my specs, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant SearchEngine::BING_CONFIG
```

Comment: You may add `puts 'adding constant'` to your initializer. After that you will be able to check if file loaded properly. If so, then problem is in namespaces.

Comment: Constant variable? It's self-contradiction.

Comment: ya, I removed that... I don't know why I added variable in there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `BING_CONFIG = …` string resides in your class/module `SearchEngine`? If yes, try to

```
require 'search_engine'
```

(or how the file containing that class is called) in top of your `rspec` file. If no, fix the problem with namespaces, e.g.:

```
SearchEngine::BING_CONFIG = …
```

Comment: My rpsec file includes my class and the namespace seems to be in place. the error I get is: `uninitialized constant SearchEngine::BING_CONFIG`

Comment: Would you show us the whole `config/initializers/bing.rb` file?

Comment: That is the whole file.

Comment: Than try to modify it according to the second suggestion in my answer: `BING_CONFIG = …` ⇒ `SearchEngine::BING_CONFIG = …`

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, as far as you configure such a initialization in `config/initializers`, it should be loaded even in rspec run. But it is still not working...

Since your error output showing `SearchEngine` name, I guess you've wrapped the initializer inside a module.

If that is the case, the `SearchEngine` module name should be introduced before the above assignment. But when you introduce the module name, to make Rails's autoloader happy, you must follow Rails' way of naming files (and class/module name) according to the namespace hierarchy. And it's depends on how `SearchEngine` is defined. How do you want to define the module name?

Comment: I've set up a class here: `app/services/search_engine.rb` As I mentioned, my rails console loads the constant variable just fine. It just doesn't seems to work in my tests. I don't seem to understand why.

Comment: Rails don't know about `services` path. Try move that below `app/models` (regardless of whether it is module or not) and run.

Comment: I added this to my application.rb file: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services)` wouldn't that make sure rails new about my services directory?

Comment: As far as I tested while ago (to implement logics independent of `ActiveRecord`), it worked. But by some reason which I can't remember, I sticked to place the logic into `app/models`. Please try to place somewhere  rails already know of first..